# rails client_side_validations only on hit save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation

I don't want the clien-side-validations validate on blur the inputs, just when I hit save.

Is this possible?
How can I do this?

I have just some simple validations (empty, basically)... and I'm thinking about write it by hand.. does it worth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it with pure Javascript or with the help of any of JQuery/Prototype and similar frameworks.

Here is a code that I tried with JQuery

```
<html>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <form id="my_form" action="http://google.com?q=ruby" method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" /> <br/>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" /> <br/>
            <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" /> <br/>
            <input id="form_button" type="button" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form_button").on('click', function() {
            var form_valid = true;
            $("#my_form > input[type='text']").each(function() {
                if(this.value == "") {
                    var error_span_present = $(this).next("span").length != 0;
                    if(!error_span_present) {
                        $("<span style='color:red;'>" + $(this).attr("placeholder") + " cannot be Blank </span>").insertAfter($(this));
                    } 
                    else { 
                        $(this).next("span").html($(this).attr("placeholder") + " cannot be Blank");
                    } 
                    form_valid = false;
                }   
                else {
                    if($(this).next("span").length != 0) {
                        $(this).next("span").remove();
                    } 
                }
            });
            if(form_valid){ 
                $("#my_form").submit();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NbD5q/) that demos this code.

Hope this helps

Comment: actually, I just leave it with HTML5 validations and some CSS. Thanks for your answer anyway, it should work =) cheers